# Using 'Either' in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, either

I have two values, `t1` and `t2`, of type `Either String Type`. The `Left`-value is used for error handling. These values are used in a function which returns `Either String Type`.

What I want to do is check if both `t1` and `t2` are `Right`-values and satisfy `p :: Type -> Bool`. If they do, I want to return `Right (the type inside t1)`. If both `t1` and `t2` are `Right`-values, but do not satisfy `p`, I want to return `Left someString`. If one of `t1` or `t2` is a `Left` value, I just want to pass on that value.

How can I do this in an elegant way? I have a hunch that using Either as a monad is the right thing to do, but I'm not sure of how to go about it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why monads?

```
test p (Right t1) (Right t2) | p t1 && p t2 = Right t1
                             | otherwise = Left "nope"
test _ (Left t1) _ = Left t1
test _ _ (Left t2) = Left t2
```

Answer (score 5):

If you do want to do it with a `Monad` it would look something like this, but the `Monad` instance for `Either` was recently changed so that this won't actually work in recent GHCs:

```
do v1 <- t1
   v2 <- t2
   guard (p v1 && p v2) `mplus` Left someString
   return v1
```

Comment: It does work with GHC 7.0.3 if I import `Control.Monad.Error` from `mtl` package. One can also complete abstraction from `Either` by replacing `Left` with `throwError . strMsg`. Not that it's terribly useful though.

Comment: Can you give more details on the change, specifically what changed and when?

Comment: mightybyte: the only change I know of is that 'fail' no longer maps to 'Left'. I'm not sure how that affects the above example, though.

Comment: @Antoine Latter: `guard False = mzero`, but `Either a` is not an instance of `MonadPlus` as the instance is defined in `Control.Monad.Instances` and does not have access to the `Error` class from the `Control.Monad.Trans.Error` which is out in `transformers`. `mtl` then re-exports the instance via `Control.Monad.Error`.

Comment: @mightybyte: We moved the instance for `Either` from `transformers` (and before that `mtl`) into `base`, but as the instance involves both a class _and_ a type from the Prelude and isn't stated by any current Haskell standard, we had to export it from `Control.Monad.Instances` rather than just put it into scope everywhere. In the process we removed the assumption of `Error` from the left hand argument to `Either`. This had the side-effect of changing the behavior of `fail`, from `Left . strMsg` to `error`. We left `MonadPlus` and `Alternative` in `transformers`.

Comment: @mightybyte: As to when, about a year or so back, we had the discussion on the libraries mailing list.

Answer (score 4):

You could create your own Error datatype and make it instance of Monad.

```
data Computation a = Error String | Result a


instance Monad Computation where
    (Result x)  >>= k   =  k x
  e@(Error a)   >>= k   =  e
```

And then use the [method described by Ganesh Sittampalam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290712/using-either-in-haskell/6290743#6290743). (You will need to add an instance MonadPlus Computation too.

**Update** for completeness it would look like this:

```
import Control.Monad

data Computation a = Error String | Result a



instance Monad Computation where
  return a = Result a
  (Result x)  >>= k   =  k x
  (Error a)   >>= k   =  Error a

instance MonadPlus Computation where
  mzero              = Error "Always fail"
  mplus (Error a) r  = r
  mplus l         _  = l


check :: (Int -> Bool) -> Computation Int  
check p =   do v1 <- Result 4
               v2 <- Result 2
               guard (p v1 && p v2) `mplus` Error "someString"
               return v1
```

Comment: Your definition of `mplus` does not do what you want it to do.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito, I fxied the code so mplus shows proper behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate out the monadic action from the propagation of `Left` values if you really want to:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Instances
```

This yields the simple monadic action:

```
foo :: Type -> Type -> Either String Type
foo t1 t2 | p t1 && p t2 = Right t1
          | otherwise    = Left somestring
```

Which you can apply to monadic arguments to get the function you want, using

```
fooM :: Either String Type -> Either String Type -> Either String Type
fooM t1 t2 = join (foo <$> t1 <*> t2)
```

or equivalently

```
fooM t1 t2 = do
    a <- t1
    b <- t2
    foo a b
```